# Summation that gets smaller with greater index

Tags: calculus, summation

Question: Given a summation $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ , where are starting value $k=1$, and our ending value is n. Come up with a summation example where the sum is less when $n=10$ and $n=5$.

My example is $1/e_n$. I get around 0.03368 when $n=5$ and 0.000453 when $n=10$.

My Question: Are there any other examples without the use of exponentials? If so is their a trick to coming up with these examples, I mean like this was suppose to be an easy exercise, but I kept thinking about it and realized how weak my math skills are. Generally are there any math cues to make summations smaller like there are for making a fraction smaller ( i.e make the denominator bigger than the numerator)

Comment: suppose $a_k < 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality
$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}a_k < \sum_{k=1}^{5}a_k$$
is equivalent to the inequality
$$\sum_{k=6}^{10}a_k < 0$$
so no need for a special trick; just make sure the sum of the last $5$ terms is negative.

As regards your example, since all your terms are positive, the sum is increasing, so that example doesn't work.

Comment: I was wondering why my example didn't work.  The $1/e^n$ is a constant, so can be pulled in front of the summation leaving 1 as our $a_k$ term. By sum rules our summation is equal our upper value (n) which is 5 or 10 mulitiplied by our constant.

Comment: I don't follow. You're supposed to be summing the _same_ sequence. If the $10$-term series has all terms equal, then the terms of the $5$-term series are the first $5$ terms of the $10$-term series, so the sum of the $10$-term series is twice the sum of the $5$-term series.

Comment: I meant it like this 
 $\sum_{k=1}^5 1/e_n$ = $1/e^5$ + $1/e^5$ + $1/e^5$ + $1/e^5$ + $1/e^5$ = 0.033.. The n is the n representing the end value at each iteration, I did not want it to be $1/e_k$ which would be $1/e^1$ + $1/e^2$ + $1/e^3$ + $1/e^4$ + $1/e^5$

Comment: But the two series must have the same first $5$ terms.

Comment: my bad, I think I understand, thank you for your help

Comment: The problem clearly specifies _one_ series, not two. Thus, you need to compare two partial sums of the _same_ series; the sum of the first $10$ terms is being compared against the sum of the first $5$ terms.